# CorePlot - iPhone Graphs

Tags: iphone

I am getting the error

> CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or
>   directory". I have kept the
>   coreplot0.2.2 folder in the desktop. I
>   used the following path for set header
>   path.
>   "/Users/Giri/Desktop/iPhoneGraph/CorePlot
>   0.2.2/Source/framework

is it correct ? please Help Me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Girija

you need to add the core plot framework to your project by adding it as Existing framework and than in target click on the app name, click on info button on middle top of xcode and in the general tab add the core plot framework as linked libraries. something like this 
[image]